# How do I get the per-spec output of a LV-MaxSonar LV-EZ0 rangefinder with Android Things?

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, android-things

I'm using this sensor with a Raspberry Pi B 3 and Android Things 1.0

I have it connected as per [these](https://www.maxbotix.com/Raspberry-Pi-with-Ultrasonic-Sensors-144) instructions

The [spec](https://www.maxbotix.com/documents/LV-MaxSonar-EZ_Datasheet.pdf) for its output suggests I should receive "an ASCII capital “R”, followed by three ASCII character digits representing the range in inches up to a maximum of 255, followed by a carriage return (ASCII 13)"

I have connected to the device and configured it as follows (connection parameters map to the "Serial, 0 to Vcc, 9600 Baud, 81N" in that spec, I think):

```
    PeripheralManager manager = PeripheralManager.getInstance();
    mDevice = manager.openUartDevice(name);
    mDevice.setBaudrate(9600);
    mDevice.setDataSize(8);
    mDevice.setParity(UartDevice.PARITY_NONE);
    mDevice.setStopBits(1);
    mDevice.registerUartDeviceCallback(mUartCallback);
```

I am reading from its buffer in that callback as follows:

```
public void readUartBuffer(UartDevice uart) throws IOException {


    // "The output is an ASCII capital “R”, followed by three ASCII character digits
    // representing the range in inches up to a maximum of 255, followed by a carriage return
    // (ASCII 13)

    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final int maxCount = 1024;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[maxCount];
    int total = 0;
    int cycles = 0;

    int count;
    bout.write(23);
    while ((count = uart.read(buffer, buffer.length)) > 0) {
        bout.write(buffer, 0, count);
        total += count;
        cycles++;
    }
    bout.write(0);

    byte[] buf = bout.toByteArray();

    String bufStr = Arrays.toString(buf);
    Log.d(TAG, "Got " + total + " in " + cycles + ":" + buf.length +"=>" + bufStr);
}

private UartDeviceCallback mUartCallback = new UartDeviceCallback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onUartDeviceDataAvailable(UartDevice uart) {
        // Read available data from the UART device
        try {

            readUartBuffer(uart);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "Unable to access UART device", e);
        }

        // Continue listening for more interrupts
        return true;
    }
```

When I connect the sensor and use this code I get readings back of the form:

```
05-10 03:59:59.198 1572-1572/org.tomhume.blah D/LVEZ0: Got 7 in 1:9=>[23, 43, 0, 6, -77, -84, 15, 0, 0]
05-10 03:59:59.248 1572-1572/org.tomhume.blah D/LVEZ0: Got 7 in 1:9=>[23, 43, 0, 6, 102, 101, 121, 0, 0]
05-10 03:59:59.298 1572-1572/org.tomhume.blah D/LVEZ0: Got 7 in 1:9=>[23, 43, 0, 6, 102, 99, 121, 0, 0]
```

The initial 23 and the final 0 on each line are values I have added. Instead of an expected R\d\d\d\13 I expect between them, I'm getting 7 signed bytes. The variance in some of these byte values appears when I move my hand towards and away from the sensor - i.e. the values I'm getting back vary in a way I might expect, even though the output is completely wrong in form and size.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I suspect it's something extremely obvious, but I'm stumped. Examining the binary values themselves it doesn't look like bits are shifted around by e.g. a mistake in protocol configuration.

Comment: Do you have a logic analyzer to check the values coming from the uart bus? If the data being sent is unsigned but you're reading signed values, maybe you need to convert the bytes.

Comment: Thank you - I don't think that signed/unsigned difference would convert the 43 (which is coming at the start of the sequence where I'd expect an R) into 82 (ASCII R). I don't have a logic analyzer I'm afraid, maybe I need to get one :/

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it on a hardware now, but seems algorithm for reading serial data from a LV-MaxSonar LV-EZ0 rangefinder should be slightly different: you should find "an ASCII capital “R” in UART sequence buffer (because LV-EZ0 starts sending data after power on and not synchronized with Raspberry Pi board and first received byte may be not “R” and quantity of received bytes can be less or more then 5 bytes of LV-MaxSonar response^ in one buffer can be several (or part)of  LV-MaxSonar responses) and THAN try to parse 3 character digits representing the range in inches and ending CR symbol (if there is no all 3 bytes for digits and CR symbol - than start to find capital “R” again because LV-MaxSonar response is broken (it also can be)). For example take a look at [GPS contrib driver](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/tree/master/gps) especially at `processBuffer()` of [`NmeaGpsModule.java`](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/blob/master/gps/src/main/java/com/google/android/things/contrib/driver/gps/NmeaGpsModule.java) and `processMessageFrame()` of [NmeaParser.java](https://github.com/androidthings/contrib-drivers/blob/master/gps/src/main/java/com/google/android/things/contrib/driver/gps/NmeaParser.java) - the difference is in your have only one "sentence" and its start is not `"GPRMC"`, but only `"R"` symbol.

And other important thing: seems there no capital “R” (ASCII 82) in your response buffers - may be some issues in LV-MaxSonar LV-EZ0 connection. Your schematics should be exactly like top right picture on page 6 of [datasheet](https://www.maxbotix.com/documents/LV-MaxSonar-EZ_Datasheet.pdf): `Independent Sensor Operation: Serial Output Sensor Operation`. Also try, for example, to connect LV-MaxSonar LV-EZ0 to USB<->UART (with power output) cable (e.g. like [that](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/Cables/DS_TTL-232RG_CABLES.pdf)) and test it in terminal with your PC.